# Nest and Elasticsearch - understanding the basics

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am learning NEST and elastic search, and some of the basics are confusing me. If I create a basic index, using the Nest integration tests:

```
var client = ElasticsearchConfiguration.Client;

        if (client.IndexExists(ElasticsearchConfiguration.DefaultIndex).Exists)
            return;

        var projects = NestTestData.Data;
        var people = NestTestData.People;

        client.CreateIndex(ElasticsearchConfiguration.DefaultIndex, c => c
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .AddMapping<ElasticSearchProject>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
            .AddMapping<Person>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
        );
        client.CreateIndex(ElasticsearchConfiguration.DefaultIndex + "_clone", c => c
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .AddMapping<ElasticSearchProject>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
            .AddMapping<Person>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
        );

        var bulkParameters = new SimpleBulkParameters() { Refresh = true };
        client.IndexMany(projects, bulkParameters);
        client.IndexMany(people, bulkParameters);
        client.Refresh(new[] {ElasticsearchConfiguration.DefaultIndex, ElasticsearchConfiguration.DefaultIndex + "_clone"});
```

I do not understand the state of the ElasticClient after this operation.

1) Why is the ElasticClient still Valid = False after this operation. What does Valid mean then?

2) The CreateIndex function returns an IIndicesOperationResponse who's status property OK is set to false, even though I know the index is getting created. What does OK mean?

Comment: Are you running against Elasticsearch v1.0?

Comment: The problem was my Nest was way out of date. The current way to achieve IsValid is now with RootNodeInfo().   https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/releases/tag/0.11.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The .IsValid construct on the client was used as a one time ping in older versions to see if the client could connect to the configured host. This has long been removed since it caused more confusion and does not offer anything really.
2. Elasticsearch 1.0 has standardized and removed all the `OK` properties from responses.